# One PHP math-expression with two different results

Tags: php

```
 $z = "321";
 $x = 5;
 $y = 10.5;
 echo $x+$y*$x;
 echo "<br />";
 echo "2</br>".$x+$y*$x;
```

Output:

```
57.5<br />54.5
```

I am shocked how this output came out. Can anyone please clarify this equation?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  `$z` is a string while `$x` and `$y` are both an int.  You are also concatenating "2</ br>" onto an equation I think. What is it you are expecting from this script?

Comment: @Blinkydamo I tried putting $z into an integer and the stange 'fenomenon' still exists. To 'solve' this, I tried putting both expressions into parentheses and both results came out right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain you what happens line by line:

```
//$z = "321";
$x = 5;
$y = 10.5;
echo $x+$y*$x;
echo "<br />";
echo "2</br>".$x+$y*$x;
output///57.5 //54.5
```

you are getting different result, because you are adding string and int together.

```
echo "2</br>".$x+$y*$x;
```

means:

```
"2</br>5" + (10.5 * $x);
```

and php will convert the string into int to make the addition.

```
"2</br>5 will be converted into 2
```

and the result will be

```
2 + 52.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The 57.5 is simply the result of `5 + 10.5. * 5`. The 54.5 is a little more complicated...

Due to [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) The line

```
echo "2</br>".$x+$y*$x;
```

it equivalent to

```
echo ("2<br />" . $x) + ($y * $x)
```

which, following through, equates to

```
echo ("2<br />5"  + 52.5)
```

Because PHP is casting the left hand side of this expression to a number for the `+` operator (see [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)), you end up with

```
echo 2 + 52.5
```

which results in your **54.5**.

Answer (score 0):

From the output I'd assume that PHP follows BIDMAS (Brackets, Indices, Division and Multiplication, Addition and Subtraction) and therefore: 5 + 10.5 * 5 is equal to: 5 + (10.5 * 5) = 57.5

As for the second output, I can't see immediately why it is outputting "54.5", I will however point out that the '' should be either:

```
<br/>

<br />
```

or

```
<br>
```